# How to make submit input and text input equally spaced

Tags: css, html, input

I noticed while styling a web page when you do :

```
 <input type='text' placeholder='input1' />
 <input type='text' placeholder='input2' />
 <input type='submit'  />
```

for a form and add this css :

```
 input[type='text']{
    display:block;
}

input{
    width:400px;
}
```

There are some difference between the width of the text inputs and the submit button ~ 20px as I think but how to make them equally large ?

Here is a snippet

```css
input[type='text']{
    outline:none;
    border:1px solid lightgrey;
    border-radius:3px;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}

input{
    width:400px;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' placeholder='input1' />
<input type='text' placeholder='input2' />
<input type='submit'  />
```

I tried resting the margin and padding but it doesn't work why ?

Comment: Running the code snippet does not show any difference. You may want to reconsider how you worded this question. That or I am misunderstanding what you are asking.

As a suggestion, you could try 

`width: 100%;`
`margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the button uses

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Which means the border (and all padding) is included in the width.  The text box does not have that rule so appears 2px larger (1px for each border, left & right).

Add the box-sizing rule to the text box and they will be the same width.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the in the placeholders the borders and padding are added to the total, so this `<input type="text" placeholder="input1" style="border-width: 1px; padding: 1px;"></input>` becomes a placeholder which measures 404 pix. (400 + 1px right border + 1px left border + 1 px left padding + 1 px right padding).

In the submit's case, this: `<input type="submit" style="border-width: 20px;  padding: 20px;">` becomes a 400 px button with a wide border but still will be 400px wide. The padding will affect mostly to the text, which will still be centered, so it won't be very noticeable. If you apply some unilateral padding, like `padding-right:300px`, you will notice.